# Android Multiple users log in to Facebook api 3

Tags: android, facebook, android-activity, oauth

How can I allow multiple users to log in via facebook SDK?

It seems that the sdk is using the local native facebook app, so the user currently logged in is who gets authorised, but I want to be able to authorise others.
Is there anyway to force it go through the web dialog view where maybe a user can log in?

I ask this as some users of my app will have a personal and work account and want to be able to access both.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the SwitchUserSample that ships with the SDK.

Comment: I am currently looking at it, But exactly how does one stop facebook from using the native facebook app as a cache, for a different person to log on?

Comment: When you go to open a new Session, you set the SessionLoginBehavior to be SUPPRESS_SSO, like this https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/samples/SwitchUserSample/src/com/facebook/samples/switchuser/SettingsFragment.java#L216